# how to resolve unpack error in python function

Tags: python

I was wondering why I'm getting an unpack error for `entry[1]` when the value will always be some tuple like so `Tuple[str, int]` for this function:

```
def add_to_index(index, keyword, url):
    for entry in index:
        if entry[0] == keyword:
              for curr_url, count in entry[1]:
                    if curr_url == url:
                        url_exists = True
              if not url_exists:
                    entry[1].append((url,0))
              return
(('http://www.example.com/index.html', 0), 'has error')
                curr_url, count = entry[1]
                print(count) # prints 0
    index.append([keyword, (url,0)])
index = []
add_to_index(index, 'foo', 'http://example.com/index.html')
add_to_index(index, 'foo', 'http://example.com/index.html')
```

The exception is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/Users/user/foo.py", line 58, in add_to_index
    for curr_url, count in entry[1]:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Thank you.

Comment: what the value in index at beginning

Comment: @galaxyan thanks for asking. the value of index is []. I've updated the original post as well.

Comment: in this case, it should not raise the exception. Could you post the error trace message?

Comment: I ran your code and got `('http://example.com/index.html', 0) has error` but not tuple unpacking error. Was that some other exception? Was there a traceback? Please post the error you got.

Comment: @tdelaney oops. If you remove the try except, the unpack error should appear. I'll update the code in the post as well. thank you.

Comment: I added `traceback.print_exc()` and saw the problem.

Comment: @galaxyan thank you for raising this. I just added the exception to the post which is `Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/Users/user/foo.py", line 58, in add_to_index
    for curr_url, count in entry[1]:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entry[1]` is a two-tuple `('http://example.com/index.html', 0)`. The problem is that you try to iterate that tuple. The first thing iterated is the string `'http://example.com/index.html'`, which has more that two values, giving the unpack error. Instead of iterating, just assign

```
curr_url, count = entry[1]
```

To demonstrate

```
>>> entry = ['foo', ('http://example.com/index.html', 0)]
>>> for curr_url, count in entry[1]:
...     print("success")
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Breaking the unpacking into a separate step shows the problem

```
>>> for value in entry[1]:
...     print(value)
...     curr_rul, count = value
... 
http://example.com/index.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Or `if entry[1][0] == url:` directly, might be more explicit not to use a loop if there is a single value to check ;)